# how to extract ping parameters from a file in bash script

Tags: bash, ping

I have a ping file like this

```
PING 172.17.9.1 (172.17.9.1) 1000(1028) bytes of data.
1008 bytes from 172.17.9.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.943 ms
1008 bytes from 172.17.9.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.855 ms
1008 bytes from 172.17.9.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.860 ms
.
.
--- 172.17.9.1 ping statistics ---
100 packets transmitted, 100 received, 0% packet loss, time 9958ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.836/1.710/37.591/4.498 ms
```

I want to extract the packet loss, time, average rtt with bash scripting. what should I do?!
Thanks

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314219/how-to-get-the-percent-of-packets-received-from-ping-in-bash
And draw your own conclusions

Comment: You should start with reading [ask]. The `man grep` and `man sed` could help too.

Comment: I'm new in here, Thank u anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
awk -F',|/' '/time/{x=$3$4}/rtt/{print x " " $5}' ping.txt | sed 's/[^0-9 .]*//g'
Output:
0 958 1.710
```

Comment: Thank you, but I just want the numbers, not the strings between them.

Comment: You could just remove all the characters post like  `| sed 's/[^0-9 ]*//g' or you could use gsub to remove all characters other than digits. See edited answer. I used sed as i didnt wanted to complicate awk.

Answer (score 2):

You can `awk` as

```
$ awk -F"[,/]" '/packet loss/{print $3} /rtt/{print " rtt",$2,$5}' input
 0% packet loss
 rtt avg 1.710
```